# How to move the cursor to the correct indentation level without quiting insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, insert-mode

For example I have this JavaScript code. The `|` character represents the cursor position and it is on an empty line.

```
function a() {
    console.log("a");

    function b() {
        console.log("b");

        function c() {
            console.log("c");
        }
|
        c();
    }

    b();
}
```

After the requested operation, the contents would look like this:

```
function a() {
    console.log("a");

    function b() {
        console.log("b");

        function c() {
            console.log("c");
        }
        |
        c();
    }

    b();
}
```

What I am asking for is a mapping command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @jamessan mentioned, `<C-f>` will indent to the correct place from insert mode. You can also use `<C-t>` and `<C-d>` to increase or decrease the indention level from insert mode.

However, you may be able to avoid getting into that situation completely by using one of the following techniques:

- Use `o`/`O` to start a new line from a previous line
- Use `cc`/`S` to edit the line (takes indention into consideration)

For more help see:

```
:h cc
:h S
:h o
:h i_CTRL-T
:h i_CTRL-F
```

Comment: Also, `<C-f>` is typically defined in `'indentkeys'` or `'cinkeys'` (depending on which indent mechanism is being used) which will allow you to reindent the current line to where it should be, from insert mode.  See [:help i_CTRL-F](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#i_CTRL-F)

Comment: Note you need to `:set cindent` or these keys do nothing!