# Unintended tabulation bind

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm kinda new to vim, and I wanted to play with macros.

I wrote a bunch to fit with my previous muscle memory, including this one:

```
 imap <C-i> <ESC>m`$a<CR><ESC>==k``i
```

The intended behavior was to create a line below the cursor, but keep editing the line. First it never really worked, and second, I could isolate this line of being responsible of something strange:

As soon as I add it, the Tab button is having exactly the same behavior as the CTRL+i button in edition mode. I may miss something obvious, would anyone have any idea?

THanks

Answer (score 2):

First you might want to read [`:h o`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#o) and [`:h O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#O) which are built-in command to add new lines in normal mode.

In insert mode these mappings are what you are trying to do (see [`:h i_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dO)):

```
inoremap <c-k> <c-o>O
inoremap <c-j> <c-o>o
```

Now about why your `tab` key stops working: it is because your terminal sends the same keycode for `<c-i>` and `tab`. You can see it in insert mode by pressing <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>ctrl+i</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. (See [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dV)).

I made [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) some time ago to help people debug this kind of problems.

Comment: Huh wait I expressed myself wrong. What I want to do is to insert a line above/below *without* moving the cursor (it should stay in the same place in the line) nor quitting the insert mode.

Comment: @LoicCoenen, the best way to insert blank lines without moving the cursor (and without any side effect) is with `i_CTRL+O` + `append()`. See this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10892/626