# Get correct indentation when entering insert mode

Tags: insert-mode

When I enter insert mode using `o` or `O` when programming, the cursor appears at the correct level of indentation. In this example below, X is the place where I press `o` and `Y` is where my cursor appears.

```
func doX() error{X
      Y
}
```

But if I'd do this

```
func doX() error{
X
}
```

Now where I press X is also where my cursor appears. What I want is:

```
func doX() error{
X    Y
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense!

`o/O` enter newlines whilst `i` just goes to insert mode, I expect that to be the 'problem' but I'm wondering if this can be fixed? I don't want `i` to enter a new line, just to start editting at the right indentation point. (If the line is empty).

Preferably another key than `i` :)

Thanks!

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-correct-indentation-level-without-quiting-insert-m

Comment: Your question is good, it was only asked before :-) But don't worry, your contributions are still welcomed.

Comment: But that question is about when you are already in insert mode :O mine is to jump to insert mode at the correct level of indentation :)